# Javascript cannot parse JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I was trying to parse this JSON string:

> {"query": "my schedule today","type": "timeline","title": "Today
>   events:","time":["2015-07-06\n20:30:00"],"summary":["Weekly meeting +
>   Show & Tell (Hangout)"],"description":["Weekly Bullets (20 minutes):
>   "]}

This is a valid JSON (checked on jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com). However, I received erorr:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token

in (file angular.js):

```
function fromJson(json) {
    return isString(json)
        ? JSON.parse(json)
        : json;
}
```

Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Try posting a demo, there is a button in the toolbar to demonstrate your issue. Or try jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `\n` in the text, you need to escape it to `\\n`

```js
var json = '{"query": "my schedule today","type": "timeline","title": "Today events:","time":["2015-07-06\\n20:30:00"],"summary":["Weekly meeting + Show & Tell (Hangout)"],"description":["Weekly Bullets (20 minutes): "]}'

console.log(JSON.parse(json))
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json)))
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the string you are working with is the result of an external call and you can't change the `\n` to `\\n` manually, then this can be achieved with a simple replace:

```
json = json.replace(/\\n/g, "\\\n");
```

Comment: thanks but this is actually not about "\n" problem. What I posted was a JSON data, not a string. I tried removing it and there was the same error. I think the problem is in the key "description" because it ran fine when I delete the last space in "Weekly Bullets (20 minutes): "

Comment: @HưngCaoXuân in that case you need to share your complete code... like the `isString()` method and a way to recreate the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, a `\n` token in your string, let remove it:

```js
var data = '{"query": "my schedule today","type": "timeline","title": "Today events:","time":["2015-07-06\n20:30:00"],"summary":["Weekly meeting + Show & Tell (Hangout)"],"description":["Weekly Bullets (20 minutes): "]}'.replace('\n', '');
var data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data.query);
```

Hope this helps.